Firebase + Facebook Invalid OAuth access token
Im working on a Unity mobile application. The Login is integrated with firebase. Login with appleID and google account is fine. However, encountered an issue wh
en doing Facebook login.
I can login with Facebook account and get the token. but I got the below error msg with pass the token with FacebookAuthProvider.GetCredential(fbAccessToken).
The error msg :

System.AggregateException: One or more error occurred, (Bad access token: {"code":190, "message":"Invalid OAuth access token - Cannot parse access token"})

The code I process the login. Im using UniversalSDK third party library to do Facebook login and get the user login token. After that , pass the token string to firebase for credential.
UniversalSDK.Ins.Login(LoginType.FACEBOOK).OnSuccess(result =>{
  string fbAccessToken = result.IdToken;
  string userName = result.Name;
  Credential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.GetCredential(fbAccessToken);
  notDestory.auth.SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>{
    if (!handleFireBaseAuthError(task))
    {
      var result = task.Result;
      result.User.TokenAsync(true).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task_jwt =>{
        RequestHTTPServerUserInfo(task_jwt.Result, 1, () => { });
      });
    }
  });
}).OnError(result => {
    alert_Box.SetTypeWithDelegateCallback(Common_alert_box.AlertType.Reminder, CommonConfig.GetLangWithKey("login_facebook_failed"));
});

In my case, Turned on the Facebook auth service and filled the appID with secret on Firebase. the Facebook application have not yet review completely.  Do I required to submit for first review before firebase can pass the access?


Finally, found out the answer for this cases.
The main points :

check the login requesting web page is it calling : limited.facebook.com
check does the iOS ATT is requested in a right way
iOS device privacy tracking turned off as default

The references :

Facebook iOS SDK v17.0 error: If you are not using Limited Login, you will need to handle all Graph API calls using Graph API
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/limited-login/ios

